# Topology on the extended real line

Tags: general-topology

In our real analysis class we are working through 'Real and Complex Analysis' by Rudin and covered topological spaces (but not bases, subbases and other ways of generating  topologies, so I can't use these in the exercise).

Let $\tau =$ the collection of sets $(a,b),[-\infty,a),(a,\infty]$ and any union of these types. Show that $\tau$ is a topology.

Here's my approach:

1. $\mathbb{R} \in \tau$ since $\mathbb{R} = [-\infty,a)\cup(a,\infty]$. $\emptyset \in \tau$.
2. For any $A_1,A_2,\ldots \in \tau,$ we have $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i) \in \tau.$
3. For any $A_1,\ldots,A_n \in \tau$, we have $\bigcap_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i) \in \tau.$

However, I feel like my approach is too naive and I'm missing some details.

Comment: The extended real line is $X = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$? If so, then you have to replace $\mathbb{R}$ in 1. with $X$ and this would almost work (you are missing $a$ on the left hand side in 1. but this is easily fixed by taking $[-\infty,1) \cup (0,\infty]$ or something similar). In 2. and 3. you took $A_i$ to be some interval $(a_i,b_i)$ which you cannot assume as $\tau$ contains many sets which are not intervals but union of intervals. The union of the union of intervals is still a union of intervals, so 2. is still easy. But in 3. you really have to prove something which you did not.

Comment: This is strange, as $(-\infty,\infty)$ is just $\mathbb{R}$. Are you sure you do not mean $[-\infty,\infty]$ in the sense of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$?

Comment: I might have made a mistake when taking notes since I was sitting in the back and from afar the brackets looks similar. In the book, $[-\infty,\infty]$ is used to that appears to be the case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this part: "But in 3. you really have to prove something which you did not"?

Comment: The problem in 3. is to show that the intersection of (unions of) intervals at hand is contained in $\tau$, that is, to prove that this intersection of (unions of) intervals is a union of intervals.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could take a look at my answer.

Comment: In general, this type of construction is called the order topology. You can define it on any totally ordered set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my attempt at another answer, please comment if there are still some parts missing/wrong.

Let $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty,\infty]$ and let $b <a$. Then we have $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = [-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty] \in \tau$. Next, let $a =b$ so that $(a,b) = \emptyset \in \tau$.

Now, we define $A = \bigcup_{j \in J} A_j = \bigcup_{j \in J}\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}(a_i,b_i)\right)$. Then $A \in \tau$ since the unions of the unions of intervals is a union of intervals, which are in $\tau$.

Last, we define $A = \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j = \bigcap_{j \in J} \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}(a_i,b_i)\right).$ Then, for any $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i),$ $x \in A$ and so A is open. (this doesn't feel correct..)

Comment: Your $A_j$ are still not arbitrary elements of $\tau$. Note that a typical element of $\tau$ is of the form $\bigcup_{r} [-\infty,x_r) \cup \bigcup_{s} (a_s,b_s) \cup \bigcup_{t} (y_t , \infty]$, so you have to take your $A_j$ to be of this form. Also note that the index sets used to describe $A_j$ as a union of intervals depends on $j$. As for the part concerning the finite (!) intersection of the $A_j$, you are supposed to show that for any $x \in \bigcap_{j} A_j$ there exists an interval $[-\infty,a_x)$, $(b_x,c_x)$ or $(d_x,\infty]$ containing $x$ and being contained in $\bigcap_{j} A_j$.