# What Is Wrong Being Compactness of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$ and Is $(0,1]$ Compact in $\mathbb R^{+}$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I know that any [a,b] are compact. However, if it is compact, then $f(\,[0,1]\,)$ with the continuous function $f(x)=\ln(x)$ would be compact too, but $f(\,[0,1]\,)=(-\infty,0]$ which is not compact. What is wrong with that?

For second question, I think $(0,1]=[0,1]$ and it is compact in $\mathbb R^{+}$ considering $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^+$. But with the same logic in first question, it seems not compact. What is wrong with that?

Comment: The log function isn’t defined at $0$: you’re actually looking at the image of $(0,1]$, which is not compact.

Comment: $(0,1]=[0,1]$ is wrong.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for your answer, I edited the question, can you help me with 2nd question too?

Comment: @PaulFrost Aren't they equal in $\mathbb R^{+}$

Comment: No, $(0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^+$, but $[0,1]$ is not.

Comment: @PaulFrost can't we say that $(0,1]$ includes all of its limit points in $\mathbb R^{+}$ ? (by closedness of  $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$, it has all of limit points in  $\mathbb R$)

Comment: @TahaDirek: Yes, $(0,1]$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^+$, but that does not make it compact, and it **certainly** does not make it equal to $[0,1]$: $0$ is in $[0,1]$ and not in $(0,1]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I meant equal in $\mathbb R^{+}$ likewise $(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)=[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$ in $\mathbb Q$, isn't it correct? I was thinking that closedness and boundedness imply compactness, but realized that it isn't, thanks for that

Comment: @TahaDirek: That is an improper use of the word *equal*. What you mean is that they have the same intersection with $\Bbb R^+$. No, it is not correct to say that $(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)=[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$ in $\Bbb Q$; what **is** correct is to say that $(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q=[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So, we can't define $(0,1]$ as a closed interval, thus my conclusion of  $(0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb R^{+}$ is wrong, is it correct?

Comment: @TahaDirek: That is correct: a closed interval includes both of its endpoints.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for your effort, all the best :)

Comment: @TahaDirek: You’re welcome!

Comment: Compactness is an absolute property of a space $X$, it does not depend on a bigger ambient space $Y \supset X$. The sets $U_n = (1/n,1]$ form an (infinite) open cover of $(0,1]$, but there does not exist a finite subcover. Hence $(0,1]$ is not compact.

Comment: @PaulFrost  I got the idea, thanks for all :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $\ln$ is only defined on $(0,\infty)$, thus it does not make sense to consider $f([0,1])$.

Moreover, we have $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(x) = -\infty$, therefore there is no continuous extension of $\ln$ to a map $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$. But we can work with the extended real line $\bar {\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty \}$ and topologize it in the [well-known way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1181969). Note that $\bar {\mathbb R}$ is compact. Then $\ln$ extends continuously to $\ln : [0,\infty) \to  \bar {\mathbb R}$ by defining $\ln(0) = -\infty$. Now $\ln([0,1]) = [-\infty,0]$ which is compact.

Comment: thank you, I got the idea

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take $\log([0,1]$, since it is not well defined in zero.

But if you take $\log([\varepsilon,1]$, with $\epsilon>0$, then you get a compact interval as image since logarithm is continuous ***in its domain***.

Comment: thank you, I got the idea